# Send Email after form submission via email service such as Mailchimp

Tags: php, email

I currently have a form that once it is submitted I used a PHP `mail()` function to send an email to the user saying their account has been created. Unfortunately, my hosting server delays my email for several hours until it is sent. I have created a Mailchimp account and I was under the impression that I could add PHP code to my current script and it would allow me to send emails through their server. I have been unable to find this feature and I am starting to believe it does not exist.

Is there any mail service company that will allow me to use their servers to send emails to my users after the submit a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, plenty:

Mandrill is one that I use and I love it. There are others like Sendgrid and mailgun.

https://mandrill.com/  - signup for an account, create an API key and grab their sample code to hook into your own php scripts.

PHP API docs: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.php.html